# Share link on twitter with default text

Tags: c#, javascript

There is a share button for twitter on my website. onclick of that button i want to send the link of that page with default text.

I can do this but the sequence of the link and default text comes in 
   DEFAULT TEXT -- Shared link

I want the sequence 
   Shared link -- DEFAULT TEXT

Comment: If I had a few more points I would vote your question down, please provide some information so that people can help you. Perhaps a sample of the code in question?

Comment: Side note: please do not add "thank you notes" and signature to your posts. If you feel that both are necessary please discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Adding [code sample](http://www.sscce.org/) shows respect much better than even 5 forms of "thanks" in the post.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here is a link to some information on the Tweet Button specifically... https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Second of all, I think what you are trying to say is that you want that when someone Tweets your page from the "Tweet Button" on your site that it suggests some kind of default message in the text input. To do this you need to include the attribute "data-text" to your anchor and set it to the default message that you would like to display. It would look something like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-text="this is the default message">Tweet</a>
```

Just below this anchor element, you would include the javascript provided on the page that I linked to earlier in the post (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

Not sure what this post has to do with C#, maybe you should remove the tag to adhere to stackoverflow best practices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am adding my sample Code                                                                  <div class="social fl" style="margin: 0; vertical-align: middle; padding: 10px 12px 7px 0px;">
Share this on: <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Default text&url=http://abcd.com" rel="nofollow"                                            
            onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'template_window','530','450','yes','center');return false" 
              onfocus="this.blur()" class="twit"></a>
     </div>

Comment: First try adding the "data-text" attribute to your <a> tag like I told you. Which would look something like: <a href="twitter.com/share?text=Default text&url=abcd.com"; rel="nofollow" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'template_window','530','450','yes','center');retur‌​n false" onfocus="this.blur()" class="twit" data-text="your default text goes here"></a> If that doesn't work, then visit the link that I provided you and start from scratch. My guess is that you are relying on some kind of theme or plugin to populate these buttons for you, maybe you need to DIY!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got the post to work from the Controller

```
public ActionResult TwitterPostTweet()
{
    string url = "http://twitter.com/share?url={0}&text={1}&via={2}";
    url = string.Format("YOUR_URL", "YOUR_TWEET", "AUTHOR");
    return Redirect(url);
}
```